# Passing date with backslashes in a URL: Android

Tags: android

Just a simple quick question. I want to pass a date in my HTTP request. The date format is like this `22\July\2012`. Here's the URL which I am trying to pass. Where `dateChat =22\July\2012`

```
if(this.dateChat!="") {
  this.dateChat.replace("\\", "\\\\");
}
httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.116.27.107/php/Chat/xmlManipulator.php?" +
  "action="+this.action+"&username="+this.userName+
  "&chatText="+this.chatText+"&email="+this.email+
  "&callfrom="+this.callFrom+"&dateChatToRetrieve="+this.dateChat);
```

The logcat is giving the following error:

```
 07-15 20:26:40.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-15 20:26:40.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2000): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Illegal character in query at index 146:
  http://10.116.27.107/php/Chat/xmlManipulator.php?action=ReturnUserAdminChats&username=You&chatText=a&email=You&callfrom=admin&dateChatToRetrieve=5\July\2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [URLEncoder.encode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to encode dateChat